# XSLT: Prevent same elements from appearing multiple times

Tags: xslt

I am trying to use XSLT to process multiple files. Some contents from one file need to be modified using the contents of another file.

For example, find element name "type" in one file and replace its contents with the contents of element named "targetSiteCode" and so on.

Here is the first file (I am only showing the least minimal working example possible):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document>
    <component>

        <entryRelationship>
            <effectiveTime value="first time"/>                                 
            <targetSiteCode code="site" codeSystem="firstcod_esys"  codeSystemName="firstcode_name" displayName="firstcode_disp"/>
        </entryRelationship>

        <entryRelationship>
            <effectiveTime value="second time"/>
            <targetSiteCode code="LACF" 
        codeSystem="second_code_sys" codeSystemName="second_code_name" displayName="second_code_disp"/>
        </entryRelationship>                                                                

    </component>                        
</Document>
```

and the second file named "File2.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Sample>
    <receivedTime value="2016-04-04T07:03:00Z"/>
    <collect>
        <type>      
            <coding>
                <system value="somesystem"/>
                <code value="somecode"/>
                <display value="somedisplay"/>
            </coding>
        </type> 
    </collect>
</Sample>
```

Here is my XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:variable name="input" select="/" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Bundle>            
            <entry>
                <fullUrl value ="somevalue"/>           
                <resource>                          
                        <xsl:apply-templates select= "Document/component/entryRelationship"/>
                </resource>
            </entry>
        </Bundle>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match = "Document/component/entryRelationship">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="document('File2.xml')/*"/>             
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match = "Sample/receivedTime">
        <receivedTime>
            <xsl:apply-templates select = "$input/Document/component/entryRelationship/effectiveTime"/>
        </receivedTime>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="effectiveTime">
        <time>
            <xsl:attribute name="value">
                <xsl:value-of select="@displayName" />
            </xsl:attribute>
        </time>
    </xsl:template>     

    <xsl:template match = "Sample/collect/type">
        <type>
            <xsl:apply-templates select = "$input/Document/component/entryRelationship/targetSiteCode"/>
        </type>
    </xsl:template>     

    <xsl:template match="targetSiteCode">   
        <coding>
            <system >
                <xsl:attribute name="value">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@codeSystem" />
                </xsl:attribute>
            </system>
            <code>
                <xsl:attribute name="value">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@code"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </code>
            <display>
                <xsl:attribute name="value">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@displayName" />
                </xsl:attribute>
            </display>
        </coding>
    </xsl:template>         
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and this is what I am getting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Bundle>
   <entry>
      <fullUrl value="somevalue"/>
      <resource>
         <Sample>
            <receivedTime>
               <effectiveTime value="first time"/>
               <effectiveTime value="second time"/>
            </receivedTime>
            <collect>
               <type>
                  <coding>
                     <system value="firstcod_esys"/>
                     <code value="site"/>
                     <display value="firstcode_disp"/>
                  </coding>
                  <coding>
                     <system value="second_code_sys"/>
                     <code value="LACF"/>
                     <display value="second_code_disp"/>
                  </coding>
               </type>
            </collect>
         </Sample>
         <Sample>
            <receivedTime>
               <effectiveTime value="first time"/>
               <effectiveTime value="second time"/>
            </receivedTime>
            <collect>
               <type>
                  <coding>
                     <system value="firstcod_esys"/>
                     <code value="site"/>
                     <display value="firstcode_disp"/>
                  </coding>
                  <coding>
                     <system value="second_code_sys"/>
                     <code value="LACF"/>
                     <display value="second_code_disp"/>
                  </coding>
               </type>
            </collect>
         </Sample>
      </resource>
   </entry>
</Bundle>
```

As you can see, both the `effectiveTime` and `coding` appear twice. This is what I would like to have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Bundle>
   <entry>
      <fullUrl value="somevalue"/>
      <resource>
         <Sample>
            <receivedTime>
               <effectiveTime value="first time"/>            
            </receivedTime>
            <collect>
               <type>
                  <coding>
                     <system value="firstcod_esys"/>
                     <code value="site"/>
                     <display value="firstcode_disp"/>
                  </coding>                  
               </type>
            </collect>
         </Sample>
         <Sample>
            <receivedTime>               
               <effectiveTime value="second time"/>
            </receivedTime>
            <collect>
               <type>                  
                  <coding>
                     <system value="second_code_sys"/>
                     <code value="LACF"/>
                     <display value="second_code_disp"/>
                  </coding>
               </type>
            </collect>
         </Sample>
      </resource>
   </entry>
</Bundle>
```

Comment: Why do you need the second file? You don't seem to get any **values** out of it, only structure. Why not incorporate this in your stylesheet?

Comment: The problem is that there are some nodes where I need to copy an entire node that may have several children "as is" from File2 but then modify only one element from that entire section. So, I don't know. I know it does not look pretty but I don't know how it can be done (much) better. In theory, I could incorporate the entire content of the file (there are many) into the style sheet and modify where necessary but that would make the stylesheet too big and would (imo) look even less prettier. Besides, it is perhaps good to separate the stylesheet from content?

Comment: A structure that needs to populated with content taken from the input XML is a *template*. IMHO it would be best to write it as an *XSLT* template and use it as such. You can include or import templates from other stylesheets, if you wish.